# How to obtain additional data from a Discriminant Function Analysis?

Tags: r, linear-discriminant

I'm doing a discriminating function analysis, but I can't get the data from the Eigen values, the square chi, the canonical correlation and other data that are usually to know the robustness of each function.
If I try

```
eigenvalues <- lda_model$values
```

I obtain NULL

I hope you can help me know with what functions I can get this data

Comment: Run `str(lda_model)` to explore the object. If you are unable to find what you want, please provide the community a way to reproduce your issue in order to help you, with an example of your data set (perhaps by using `dput()`, and the code used to run the DFA.